# Trouble with for looping column values into an API call

Tags: r, loops, jsonlite

I am working on a project where I am trying to take a dataframe that is only one column which contains words and then trying to build a loop that will pull some data for the word from the Merriam-Webster API and then place it into a new dataframe.

The final data frame would hopefully look like this:

```
name | class | pronunciation | definition
ambit  noun    am*bit          circuit, compass
```

My code so far:

`words_for_loop` dataframe

```
diurnal  
omnibus 
chatelaine 
mantic 
limitrophe 
oaf
```

Code:

```
for (i in seq_along(words_for_loop)) {

url_word_vector <- paste("https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/", words_for_loop[[i]], "?key=numbers", sep = "")
  

data_holder <- tibble()

data_loop <- fromJSON(url_word_vector, flatten = TRUE) %>% 
  select(meta.id, fl, hwi.hw, shortdef) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(name = meta.id, class = fl, pronunciation = hwi.hw, definition = shortdef)  
   

data_holder <-
  data_holder %>%
  bind_rows(data_loop)

}
```

The result is an empty tibble. I think I'm on the right track, as the result for running `url_word_vector` is:

```
[1] "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/diurnal?key=99820690-b2a0-4aa3-902a-f54c7fa3c685"   
[2] "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/omnibus?key=99820690-b2a0-4aa3-902a-f54c7fa3c685"   
[3] "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/chatelaine?key=99820690-b2a0-4aa3-902a-f54c7fa3c685"
[4] "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/mantic?key=99820690-b2a0-4aa3-902a-f54c7fa3c685"    
[5] "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/limitrophe?key=99820690-b2a0-4aa3-902a-f54c7fa3c685"
[6] "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/oaf?key=99820690-b2a0-4aa3-902a-f54c7fa3c685"
```

I just don't know how to get it to loop over those individual calls. Do I need to nest a loop inside of a loop? Just looking for the next step. Thanks!

Comment: (1) You are using `words_for_loop[[1]]` inside your loop. Did you misspelled `words_for_loop[[i]]`? (2) You define `data_holder <- tibble()` inside your loop. This causes `data_holder` to be emptied in every iteration of your loop. I think you move this one _outside_  the loop. (3) I think you want to pipe the `bind_rows` part right after the `rename` function and assign this directly to `data_holder`. In this case you don't need the `data_loop`.

Comment: to (1): My mistake. I expected `words_for_loop` to be a vector.

Comment: Hey Martin, [[1]] should be [[i]]

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to get all the results in a list and `rbind` them at the end.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

words_for_loop <- data.frame(V1 = c("diurnal", "omnibus", "chatelaine", 
                                    "mantic", "limitrophe", "oaf"))

home <- "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/"

key <- "my-api-key"

url_word_vector <- paste0(home, words_for_loop[[1]], "?key=", key)

do.call(rbind, lapply(url_word_vector, function(url) {
  fromJSON(url, flatten = TRUE) %>% 
    select(meta.id, fl, hwi.hw, shortdef) %>% 
    rename(name = meta.id, class = fl, pronunciation = hwi.hw, definition = shortdef) %>%
    as_tibble()
}))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#>    name              class                     pronunciation          definition
#>    <chr>             <chr>                     <chr>                  <list>    
#>  1 diurnal:1         adjective                 di*ur*nal              <chr [3]> 
#>  2 diurnal:2         noun                      diurnal                <chr [2]> 
#>  3 omnibus:1         noun                      om*ni*bus              <chr [2]> 
#>  4 omnibus:2         adjective                 omnibus                <chr [2]> 
#>  5 justitia omnibus~ Latin phrase              jus*ti*tia om*ni*bus   <chr [1]> 
#>  6 quod semper, quo~ Latin quotation from {i_~ quod sem*per, quod ub~ <chr [1]> 
#>  7 the man on the C~ noun phrase               the man on the Clapha~ <chr [1]> 
#>  8 chatelaine        noun                      chat*e*laine           <chr [3]> 
#>  9 mantic            adjective                 man*tic                <chr [1]> 
#> 10 limitrophe        adjective                 lim*i*trophe           <chr [1]> 
#> 11 oaf               noun                      oaf                    <chr [2]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hey Allan, Thanks so much for your response. I tried the framework you provided, but have hit a snag. I created a function `dictionary_reader`, but when I use `url_word_vector` as the argument, I get this following error:

`Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'dictionary_reader(url_word_vector)' is not a function, character or symbol`

I think I misinterpreted your suggestion. Could you help me to clarify what you were intending? Thanks!